# Publish a library for client and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, ecmascript-6

Following my previous question, I have followed webpack guidelines of using multiple targets to build my NPM package. https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/#multiple-targets

I now have two different output files, index.js which is the browser bundle and index.node.js which is obviously supposed to run on the backend.

The app should run on both browser and Node, the code is mostly reused but there is some big difference around accessing files etc. which means I do need two separate files depending on what platform should the app run.

My question is how should I publish this library in a way that user can consume it like `import {//SOME OBJECT} from 'my-published-library'` when they import it from NPM regardless if they are using it on the browser or in their node application? If I try that at the moment it always defaults to index.js which works in the browser but not in Node.

Comment: Only newer Node.js versions support ESM and only using the `--experimental-modules` flag. So the broader Node.js ecosystem is not capable of consuming ESM just yet. The standard is still CommonJS and you should use that if you want to publish a package to npm.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to say? My index.node.js works perfectly fine in node, the problem is that when I import the library in node it always point to index.js (the browser version) by default and not index.node.js

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but if you are installing for the browser, the `package.json` provides a field to set the entry point.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#browser